# Vector Subscript out of Range; Comparing Elements of Vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I am currently working on a program that finds prime numbers, I know there are less convoluted ways to find prime numbers but I'm trying to practice comparing elements in vectors (not_prime_numbers & number bank(numbers from 1-100)) and when a value that is a prime number is found it is put into the final prime_number vector.

I am using loops to compare elements inside the vectors. When I ask the program to display the vector not_prime_numbers this is not a problem, nor number bank, however when I ask it to display the prime_number vector I get the error vector subscript out of range. Why are the vector elements in prime numbers I am asking to display out of range however using the same loop method to display the elements of vectors not_prime_numbers & number_bank work. Is it a problem with how I compared the two vectors to put the element into a third vector (prime_numbers)?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

int main()
{
float i = 1.0;
unsigned int n = 0;
std::vector<float>not_prime_numbers;
std::vector<float>number_bank;
std::vector<float>prime_numbers;

while (i <= 100.0)
{
    for (float j = 1.0;j<(i);++j)
    {
        float p = i / j;
        if (abs(floor(p)) == p&&j!=1.0)
        {
            not_prime_numbers.push_back(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    ++i
}

for (float k = 1.0; k <= 100.0; ++k)
{
    number_bank.push_back(k);
}

for (unsigned int m = 0; m <= number_bank.size(); ++m)
{
    while (n <= not_prime_numbers.size())
    {
        if (not_prime_numbers[n] == number_bank[m])
        {
            break;
        }
        if (n == m)
        {
            prime_numbers.push_back(number_bank[m]);
        }
        if (not_prime_numbers[n] != number_bank[m])
        {
                ++n;
        }
    }
}

std::cout << "All prime numbers between 0 and 100 are as follows:\n";
for (unsigned int j = 0; j <= prime_numbers.size(); ++j)
{
    std::cout << prime_numbers[j] << "\n";
}
}
```

This is not homework, just personal practice. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `m <= number_bank.size()` -> `m < number_bank.size()` (you make this mistake on all your loops) - otherwise you try to read one past the last element

Comment: @FuzMunkey *I get the error vector subscript out of range.* -- Are you using Visual Studio?  If so, didn't a message box pop up, giving you the option to view where the error is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in

> ```
> while (n <= not_prime_numbers.size())
> {
>    if (not_prime_numbers[n] == number_bank[m])
> ```

you go after the last element, test must be `n < not_prime_numbers.size()`

and same error when you print the result :

> ```
> for (unsigned int j = 0; j <= prime_numbers.size(); ++j)
> {
>   std::cout << prime_numbers[j] << "\n";
> }
> ```

must be

```
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < prime_numbers.size(); ++j)
{
  std::cout << prime_numbers[j] << "\n";
}
```

---

If *valgrind* is available on your host, use it to find that kind of errors and lot more

Comment: Thank you for the heads up and valgrind pointer!! There are still some logical errors to work out but I got er from here. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: The OP is claiming to get a  *vector subscript out of range.* error.  That sounds like Visual Studio.  You don't need valgrind to figure out where the error is coming from -- the Visual Studio `assert` dialog takes you to the error if you click "Retry".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, thanks for the heads up I never would have realized.